# Paso de variables desde PHP a JS funciona en Windows mas no en Linux

Tags: javascript, php, linux, apache, centos

Buenas tardes! Tengo una aplicacion web utilizando Php del lado del servidor, y JS del cliente. La aplicacion JS envia por ajax un pedido a el php, el php levanta un .ini y devuelve dicho valor. Esto en Windows esta funcionando perfectamente. El problema llega al pasar a Linux, un servidor con Centos7, en el cual no tengo manera (No encontre hasta ahora) de recibir la informacion. 
Copy-pasteo los trozos de codigo donde ocurre la falla:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["refresco"])):
  $properties = parse_ini_file("properties.ini");
  $refresh = $properties["refresco"];
  echo $refresh;

Ese es el codigo en Php. El llamado JS es:

$(document).ready(function(){

            setEventQuery();
            setEventQueryFalse()
            $.ajax({
                url:   'consultaC1.php',                //Esta libreria
                data:  "refresco", //Con este parametro
        type:  'post',          //Con este tipo de transmision de dato
                success: function(response){
                    var refresh = response * 1000;
                    console.log(refresh);
                    actualizarActualTime(refresh);
                }
            }
    );
});
```

La funcion actualizarActualTime(refresh) contiene un setInterval() con delay en refresh, como el success me devuelve "", * 1000 me arroja un 0, y termino con un bucle super acelerado...

El .ini contiene una linea asi: 
refresco = 20

Y esta ubicado en el mismo directorio que el archivo .php

No encuentro el problema, que es lo que podria estar sucediendo en Linux. Si alguien podria ayudarme... Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola! algun log de consola del navegador con algun error?

Comment: Puede que no tenga mucho que ver, pero: ¿alguna diferencia de versiones/tipo de servidores web? ¿versiones y módulos de PHP?

Comment: ¿ El servidor web está configurado para permitir cgi, fastcgi, proxy inverso, o lo que sea que utilices como pasarela ?
En Windows no se, pero en Linux suele ser necesario configurarlo a mano. Deberías de consultar la documentación del servidor en cuestión.
Como te han comentado, los logs del servidor te deberían de orientar al respecto.

Comment: No tengo ningun log de error en la consola del navegador, por lo cual llego a la deduccion de que el error es del lado del servidor. Ademas, si donde deberia levantar el ini cambio por un valor constante, tampoco le llega al JS.

Comment: Alguien podria orientarme para obtener logs del lado del servidor? En Windows corro Xampp (Apache), en Linux Apache. O para habilitar lo que sea necesario...

Comment: Los logs suelen estar en /var/log/NOMBRE_DEL_SERVIDOR, en tu caso, /var/log/apache. Y las configuraciones en /etc/apache. Cualquier guia sobre el mismo te podria orientar.

Comment: No estoy encontrando los logs de errores. Lo unico que se es que no puedo recibir nada desde el php. Asi escriba un echo "recibiendo", y del lado del javascript, en el sucess, imprimo y recibo "".

Comment: El problema podría estar en la ubicación del .ini, si la ruta actual del proceso no es la misma (caso típico en un webserver de producción), la llamada a parse_ini_file no está encontrando el fichero. Cambiala por `parse_ini_file(dirname(__FILE__)."properties.ini")` a ver si con eso se resuelve.

Comment: Pasa que el problema no se encuentra en el ini, ya que si cambio el echo $refresh; por echo 20; sigo recibiendo "" en el javascript.

Comment: Bueno, resulto ser que el llamado en Ajax no permite que envie un String, me obliga a enviarlo en el formato {"parametro" : "refresco" } Esto en Linux, en Windows tal como estaba escrito es totalmente funcional...
Ahora mi problema es que ese programita mas abajo usaba un shell_exec(java -jar xxxxxx) y almacenaba la devolucion del java, lo mismo, en Windows funcional, pero no asi en Linux, SI puedo ejecutar por terminal el java, pero no en php usando shell_exec()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo varias cosas que deberías hacer:

1. En el $.ajax donde usas `data: "refresco"` te recomiendo enviar un valor como un 1 por ejemplo, algo como `data: "refresco=1"`.
2. En las opciones del $.ajax agregar también el parámetro `dataType:"json"`. Por ejemplo:

```js
$.ajax({
  url:"consultaC1.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:"refresco=1",
  dataType:"json",
  success:function(respuesta){
    var refresh = respuesta.refresh;//valor devuelto en php
    console.log(refresh);
    actualizarActualTime(refresh);
  }
});
```

3. En el php cuando imprimes el valor `echo $refresh;` lo debes cambiar por:

   `echo json_encode(array('refresh'=>$refresh));`

Esto es para que imprima un array codificado a JSON donde la variable $refresh es el valor del campo 'refresh' para que lo pueda recibir en el ajax como respuesta.refresh.